# References to holographic medics in Star Trek TNG

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, hologram

I seem to recall one episode of TNG where a hologram was summoned to sickbay to "distract" the Borg while the personnel escaped via a hatch or similar.

I cannot recall that specific episode in more detail sorry.

My question is simply were there other references or appearances of or to holographic medics in TNG?

Comment: Was not sure if the facts about my viewing histories were relevant or not , thank you for tidying my question :) It does read better now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This was in the film [*Star Trek: First Contact*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact), not to be confused with an episode with [a similar name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Contact_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)).

Holographic EMH medics don't exist in the TNG series because they were invented (by the writers) for the Voyager TV series.

---

That being said, Doctor Crusher appeared in TNG in hologram form in [*TNG: Ship in a Bottle*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_in_a_Bottle_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))

[image]

In [*TNG: Hollow Pursuits*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hollow_Pursuits_(episode))

[image]

And alongside Nurse Ogawa in [*TNG: Future Imperfect*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Future_Imperfect_(episode))

[image]

Comment: While a holographic Dr. Crusher appears in Ship in a Bottle, I'm not sure she qualifies as a "medic", as she is acting as medical staff officer in this scene, and she doesn't perform any medic tasks, especially not on humans.

Comment: @McKay - She performs a medical examination of Moriarty.

Comment: I stand corrected on "*any* medic tasks", but it's not on a real person. And in this case, she's just a puppet of Moriarty.

Comment: @McKay - She's a hologram, she's a medic. OP never specified what level of practitioner and skill was required.

Comment: Yes. It did not matter too much if the hologram was a senior medic or an assistant etc , as long as it was a member of a medical team .

Comment: @AndyF - There are no end of holographic doctors in TNG, but not the medical sort. Einstein and Hawkins, for example.

Comment: That is a valid point. For reference I did mean medical rather than scientific personnel. :)

Comment: Love that FC scene :D

Comment: Guys, there's an obvious difference between "a hologram of someone" (ie, a fancy telephone call, a 3D telephone call), and an "artificial AI being" such as Data or The Doctor.  (Data being made of plastic, The Doctor a holodeck-like-process.)

Comment: (It's not clear which of those two (utterly different) things OP meant here?)

Comment: @Fattie: I think it is. The question is about holograms / holographic medics, not holograms *of* medics. Anyway, I don't remember holo-calls featuring prominently in TNG...

Comment: @DevSolar - sounds like you're on top of this conundrum!  Actually, I don't remember: in the three images above, is Dr. C. just a telephone call (she is somewhere else, standing and talking and so on, using a camera/whatever to pretend she is there, to trick someone), or, is the Dr.C. in those images an AI pretending to be her?  (ie, she is dead or whatever, TBC she doesn't even know this is happening and is not involved.)  IDK!

Comment: @Fattie - In the top and bottom jmages she's a hologram invented by the computer with the express purpose of fooling Riker (and the crew). In the middle one she's basically just an interactive mural

Comment: In the first one the fake Beverly is simulating a medical examination, but doing no (real) medicine on (non-holograpic) beings. In the second no medicine. In the third, the fake Beverly is an illusion not a hologram (at least not in the holodeck sense). All great examples, but they are not holograms acting in the place of doctors for Starfleet like The Doctor on Voyager (and First Contact), which is what *I* think the OP meant.